# What specifically did Einstein have in mind when he called the Israeli Freedom Party fascistic?

Tags: israel, palestine

In a [blog](https://www.the-tls.co.uk/77588-2/) published in the TLS, May 2016, Toby Lustig points out that Einstein in a letter to the *New York Times*, a few months after the declaration of Israeli idependence:

> wrote to complain of 'one of the most disturbing phenomena of our times' - the new Israeli Freedom Party, (also a precursor to today's Likud) which he described as 'closely akin in its organisation, methods and political philosophy and social appeal to the Nazi and Fascist parties'.

Toby Lustig himself was writing in the aftermath of a political scandal where Ken Livingstone had stated that the Nazi party had supported Zionism; In his blog, he points out there is evidence that justifies such a claim, but not categorically so; the Nazi Party supported Zionism, in so far as it lead to emigration of the Jewish people out of the nations of Europe but not so far as for them to establish an independent Jewish state.

My concern is with what specifically prompted Einstein to make the complaint that he did; did he refer to this in his letter, or is it made clear in any later correspondance or articles Einstein wrote?

Comment: The [letter](https://archive.org/details/AlbertEinsteinLetterToTheNewYorkTimes.December41948) itself seems easy enough to find.

Comment: "he points out there is evidence that justifies such a claim, but not categorically so; the Nazi Party supported Zionism, in so far as it lead to emigration of the Jewish people out of the nations of Europe " I can't stand the people who make these arguments; it's exactly like saying (in the context Livingstone meant it) that the Nazi's supported the _kindertransport_ in order to discredit it..

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in that same year Truman compared his opponent, Thomas Dewey, to Hitler (https://www.nytimes.com/1948/10/26/archives/president-likens-dewey-to-hitler-as-fascists-tool-says-when-bigots.html). Then as now, it means little more than "I don't like them," facts be damned. (That Einstein was a genius in physics does not, of course, give any greater weight to his opinions in other areas, although authority bias would make it seem so.)

Comment: @Meir: The article doesn't go on his reputation as a physicist, but more on the fact he witnessed the growth was of Nazism in Germany and was instrumental in helping many of his Jewish-German colleagues (though the article does not mention this).

Comment: @MoziburUllah Sometimes such experience helps a person in their work to prevent its recurrence. Other times it makes it that the person sees everything through that prism, even where inappropriate - or, to mix metaphors, to see everything as a nail because all they have is a hammer.

Comment: @Meir Hannah Arendt was also a signatory.  Given her stature as a political philosopher, *her* opinion in this matter should presumably be accorded great weight, similar to Einstein's opinions on physics.

Comment: @CMonsour ..."political philosopher _who had an affair with the Nazi philosopher Heidegger and then tried to cover up for him_." Let's not forget that crucial detail.

Comment: @Meir If you are going to use quotation marks, then give an attribution.   Anyway, the quote is misleading in that her affair with Heidegger had ended years before he became a Nazi, and there was no "cover up" since he was very publicly a Nazi.

Comment: @CMonsour "It used to be argued that Heidegger was an unworldly man who briefly blundered into Nazism; this was the exculpatory argument made by Arendt in a radio address broadcast in Germany on his 8oth birthday." (https://www.tabletmag.com/jewish-arts-and-culture/books/214226/heidegger-was-really-a-real-nazi) Sounds to me an awful lot like trying to "cover up" for him.

Comment: @Meir Interpreting an action is not even compatible with covering it up.

Comment: @CMonsour OK, then. So we have a person who knew (intimately, too) a Nazi philosopher, then tried to spin ("interpret," as you have it) his embrace of Nazism, burning books, dismissing Jewish intellectuals from the academy, etc., as a "brief blunder." Then you have the same person spinning (or "interpreting") the platform of a Jewish political party in the worst possible way, as "fascistic" - no attempt at exculpation, no attempt at "understanding." So I'm not really sure why her opinion should carry any weight whatsoever.

Comment: @Meir You're fortunate Ms. Arendt isn't alive today since saying she was intimate with a Nazi would probably be actionable.  I've already explained why that's not a true statement.  As for Ms. Arendt's statements about Heidegger and about a political party, let's just say you shouldn't expect anyone to be able to give an objective assessment of a former lover.  She is widely recognized as one of the greatest political philosophers of the last century.  She certainly hated Nazism despite your attempts at obfuscation.  I don't really understand your problem except you don't like her opinion.

Comment: @CMonsour Was Heidegger a member of the Nazi party and agreed with its anti-Semitic ideas? Then yes, Arendt was intimate with a Nazi, and I would have no problem saying that to her face. Maybe she hated Nazism, but apparently she hated her fellow Jews more (see her comments about the Eichmann trial). And that she didn't disavow Heidegger - and even restarted a romance with him _after_ the war - is telling. So no, her use of "Nazi" against a political party that had nothing to do with Nazism except that she didn't like it - is not worthy of respect in the slightest, "philosopher" or not.

Comment: @Meir: Its conveniently forgotten now but Hitler had a much larger fanbase In Europe than just the Nazis, even some Jews were for him. Arendt said that she belonged to the Jewish people and called the evil of Eichmann banal and said he must hang. How is this hating her fellow Jews?

Comment: @Meir Please cite sources that Ms. Arendt rekindled her romance with Heidegger after the war.  Wikipedia suggests romance ended in the late 1920s and was never rekindled. Heidegger became a Nazi in 1933.  (If I had an affair with a woman you *later* married and you accused me of diddling your wife, that would be slander.)  Your dismissal of Arendt in her subject of expertise reminds one of how certain ugly individuals in Europe didn't believe in relativity because of the associations of its discoverer.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Try this, for example: "Everything is organised by a police force that gives me the creeps, speaks only Hebrew and looks Arabic. Some downright brutal types among them. They would follow any order. [And she knows this - how? Because they "look Arabic" to her "cultured German" eyes?] And outside, the oriental mob, as if one were in Istanbul or some other half-Asiatic country. In addition, and very visible in Jerusalem, the peies and caftan Jews, who make life impossible for all reasonable people." (from a letter to Karl Jaspers) Other examples can be brought too.

Comment: @CMonsour "For the next two years, their love enjoyed a brief afterlife, as Heidegger wrote poems about her and told her things like “I wish I could run the five-fingered comb through your frizzy hair.”" (https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2009/01/12/beware-of-pity) Sounds like a romance to me. As for my dismissal of Arendt - greater people and bigger experts than me have done the same based on more thorough readings of her works. At any rate, for her to use her celebrity as an expert on Nazism (and the same with Einstein using his celebrity) to smear fellow Jews as Nazis is disgusting.

Comment: @Meir Heidegger pursuing Ms. Arendt is not a romance on her part.  I asked for evidence of your assertion that Ms. Arendt rekindled the romance at any time in 1933 or after.  You have provided quotations that you claim as evidence but that do not in fact support your assertion.  As this continues a pattern, perhaps we ought not to give any of your statements much credence.

Comment: @CMonsour: (1) She's the one who looked him up when she arrived in Germany in 1950, not the other way around. She also decided that all is forgiven, and spent the rest of her life trying to rehabilitate his reputation. (2) When a former paramour writes such a thing, and you accept it, then that shows receptivity to romance. (3) All I said originally was "knew (intimately, too)"; you're the one insisting that this could only mean sexual intercourse, and demanding that I produce proof thereof. (4) You might try addressing some of my other points, rather than harping on this one.

Comment: @Meir (1) Contacting someone is not the same thing as rekindling a romance. (2) On the contrary, accepting a piece of paper is often just a matter of not being rude. (3) You know very well what your words meant; don't pretend now that they meant something else. (4) You made one point about Ms. Arendt; when challenged you tried to change the subject. That doesn't make your other statements "points"; it makes them red herrings

Answer (score 14):

Copies of the [letter to the New York Times](https://archive.org/details/AlbertEinsteinLetterToTheNewYorkTimes.December41948), dated 2 December 1948 are easy enough to find online.  It is worth noting that Einstein was not the only signatory to the letter, although his is naturally the name that commentators choose to quote.

---

The paragraph quoted by Lustig itself contains part of the answer to your question:

> Among the most disturbing political phenomena of our times is the emergence in the newly created state of Israel of the "Freedom Party" (*Tnuat Haherut*), a political party closely akin in its organization, methods, political philosophy and social appeal to the Nazi and Fascist parties. ***It was formed out of the membership and following of the former Irgun Zvai Leumi, a terrorist, right-wing, chauvinist organization in Palestine***.

- (my emphasis)

Later in the letter, the authors are more explicit:

> The public avowals of Begin's party are no guide whatever to its actual character. Today they speak of freedom, democracy and anti-imperialism, ***whereas until recently they openly preached the doctrine of the Fascist state. It is in its actions that the terrorist party betrays its real character; from its past actions we can judge what it may be expected to do in the future.***

- (my emphasis)

then going on to say:

> The discrepancies between the bold claims now being made by Begin and his party, and their record of past performance in Palestine bear the imprint of no ordinary political party. ***This is the unmistakable stamp of a Fascist party for whom terrorism (against Jews, Arabs, and British alike), and misrepresentation are means, and a "Leader State" is the goal.***

- (my emphasis)

---

The full list of signatories to the letter were:

- ISIDORE ABRAMOWITZ,
- HANNAH ARENDT,
- ABRAHAM BRICK,
- RABBI JESSURUN CARDOZO,
- ALBERT EINSTEIN,
- HERMAN EISEN, M.D.,
- HAYIM FINEMAN,
- M. GALLEN, M.D.,
- H.H. HARRIS,
- ZELIG S. HARRIS,
- SIDNEY HOOK,
- FRED KARUSH,
- BRURIA KAUFMAN,
- IRMA L. LINDHEIM,
- NACHMAN MAISEL,
- SEYMOUR MELMAN,
- MYER D. MENDELSON, M.D.,
- HARRY M. OSLINSKY,
- SAMUEL PITLICK,
- FRITZ ROHRLICH,
- LOUIS P. ROCKER,
- RUTH SAGIS,
- ITZHAK SANKOWSKY,
- I.J. SHOENBERG,
- SAMUEL SHUMAN,
- M. SINGER,
- IRMA WOLFE,
- STEFAN WOLFE.